# Why is E°(cell) not ∆E°cell?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

$E^\circ_\mathrm{cell}$ is the EMF of the cell for a reaction with respect to standard hydrogen electrode (SHE). So why don't we represent $E^\circ_\mathrm{cell}$ or $E_\mathrm{cell}$ by $\Delta$ symbol, in the same manner in which we represent $\Delta H^\circ$, $\Delta G^\circ$, $\Delta S^\circ$, etc., with respect to initial absolute zero temperature?

Comment: By convention, we write $V$ or $E$ to represent a difference in potential. Adding a $\Delta$ would refer to the difference in potential difference.